# Activating IK on Existing Armature

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

How do I activate IK (Inverse Kinematics) on this rig? I feel like it has the necessary bones. I appreciate your help. I would really like to enable crouching and gyrating of hips for dance animations

Thanks, friends!

[image]

Comment: are you even sure this armature is usable? did you make it yourself? where does it come from? what sort of armature is it? I don't understand how it is supposed to work, but I'm just a post-noob and perhaps someone will answer

Comment: it should, imported from a video game